# regex (RE2) replace all occurrences of a substring between delimiters if it contains another substring

Tags: google-sheets, regexp-replace, re2

I have a source string which is a series of substring in curly brackets and separated by pound £:

{some text, property1: abc, property2: SUBSTRING, property3: {, ....}£{some text, property1: abc, property2: gcd, property3: fds, ....}£{some text, property1: abc, property2: SUBSTRING, property3: fds, ....}£

Given a SUBSTRING, I'd like to construct two RE2 expressions:

1. Gives me all {...} that DO NOT contain SUBSTRING -- so only #2
2. Gives me all {...} that DO contain SUBSTRING -- so #1 and 3

Is there a way to do it with regex (I am in google sheets so RE2)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need REGEX for this. You can use:

```
=LET(s,SPLIT(A1,"£"),FILTER(s,FIND("SUBSTRING",s)))
```

```
=LET(s,SPLIT(A1,"£"),FILTER(s,ISERR(FIND("SUBSTRING",s))))
```

To avoid dragging, you can use:

```
=MAP(A1:A,LAMBDA(s,LET(_s,SPLIT(s,"£"),FILTER(_s,FIND("SUBSTRING",_s)))))
```

```
=MAP(A1:A,LAMBDA(s,LET(_s,SPLIT(s,"£"),FILTER(_s,ISERR(FIND("SUBSTRING",_s))))))
```

Comment: This is a really beautiful solution, only that I wouldn't know how to apply it to the entire column, since I believe the FILTER function does not like to be inside ARRAYFORMULA

Comment: The only method to make your formula work for dynamic data if by first SPLITTING into columns and then doing =BYROW(D2:AA,LAMBDA(row,JOIN("£",FILTER(row,FIND("SUBSTRING",ROW)))))

Comment: You van use the MAP function. See updated answer.